# Question about odd and even part of polynomial

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

I am reading a paper, and have a next expresion 
Let $\sigma(X) \in F_{2^m}[X]$ with deg $(\sigma(X)) = \delta$, then writing $\sigma_1$ for the even part of $\sigma$ and $X\sigma'$ for the odd part of $\sigma$, obtain:
$\sigma(X) = \sigma_1(X)+X\sigma'(X)$,

My question: How to prove this?

pdta: I know that $X$ is a odd function but I don't know $\sigma'(X)$, then I am not sure whether $X\sigma'(X)$ is odd or even function, ...

Comment: Hint: Write down any polynomial, field does not matter. Do the calculation of $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma'$. The general case will jump out at you.

Comment: @AndréNicolas There is the issue that the derivative of a polynomial in $\mathbb F_{p^n}[x]$ is not defined in the usual calculus sense with limits etc but rather as a formal derivative obtained by replacing $x^i$ by $ix^{i-1}$.  If the OP has not seen (or does not remember) this, the notion of $\sigma^{\prime}$ may well be puzzling him.

Comment: I think that characteristic 2 is important because \sigma'(X) only have indeterminate with power 2, then \sigma'(X) is always even, or not? 

I have other question in the same paper say: $\sigma_1(X)$ and $\sigma'(X)$ are relative prime hwo i can proof this please

Comment: >"$\sigma_1(X)$ and $\sigma^{\prime}(X)$ are relative prime."

Are you sure you have stated the result correctly?  If $\sigma(X) = X^4 + X^3 + X + 1$, then $\sigma_1(X) = X^4 + 1 = (X+1)^4$ and $\sigma^{\prime}(X) = X^2 + 1 = (X+1)^2$ are _not_ relatively prime.

Answer (score 2):

The *formal derivative* of the polynomial
$f(x) = \sum_i f_ix^i \in \mathbb F_q[x]$ obtained by replacing each $x^i$ by $ix^{i-1}$.  Here $q=2^m$, and so the field has characteristic $2$.  Thus we have
$$
f^{\prime}(x) = \sum_{i} if_i x^{i-1}
= f_1 + f_3x^2 + f_5 x^4 + 
$$
and so $xf^{\prime}(x)$ is the *odd* part of $f(x)$, by which is meant the sum of
terms of odd degree in $f(x)$.  If $f^{(0)}(x) = \sum_i f_{2i}x^{2i}$ is the
*even* part of $f(x)$, then we have $f(x) = f^{(0)}(x) + xf^{\prime}(x)$.